# How to disable 'Live' view button for Pages in headless wagtail

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I'm using a headless wagtail as the backend of a website, where the users can create content, that serves the frontend via the v2 API.
How can I disable the 'Live' button on a Page?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the line

```
path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
```

from your project's urls.py.

This line handles front-end page serving, which is not needed on a headless site. On Wagtail 2.9 and above, the admin UI will recognise when this is missing, and leave out the 'view live' link.

Comment: When `wagtail_urls` are under the i18n_patterns, removing them breaks the reversing of localized urls. I use wagtail-localize for localization. Is there another way to remove the "Live" button?